# Draw two box plots on one axis

Tags: r, boxplot

I have two objects, say **a** and **b** which are assigned to a variable in a data set (assume battery life of iphone (a) and samsung (b))
From what I know to draw the box plot for a, I simply write

```
boxplot(a)
```

And this is working, I get a perfectly good box plot for the respective data.

My question is how do I get both the box plots **(for a and b)** on one axis?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example if you require assistance. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Not sure if this is the type of plot you are looking for... `boxplot(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data=iris)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have more options for your plot, you can use ggplot2 library. Put "a" and "b" in a dataframe, reshape the dataframe (melt) and produce a lovely plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
df=data.frame(a,b)
df$id = row.names(df)
new = melt(df,id="id")
plot = ggplot(new)+geom_boxplot(aes(variable,value,fill=variable))
ggsave("boxplots.png",plot,width=200,height=200,unit="mm")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CKRg.png)